# Check if checkbox is checked from another thread C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I check if a checkbox from my UI is checked from another thread ? As I don't have acces to UI elements from other threads ...

Thanks :).

Comment: Did my answer solve ur problem ?

Comment: Hello, yes it does :). Thanks :). Sorry for late reply, I didn't notice your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle `Checked` event of the `CheckBox` like this :

```
using System.Diagnostics;

private void Cb_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackTrace trace = new StackTrace(true);
    StackFrame[] frames = trace.GetFrames();

    foreach (StackFrame frame in frames)
        if (frame.GetMethod().Name == "InvokeDelegateCore")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Accessed from another Thread !");
            return;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use MVVM pattern, as @PMV mentioned in his answer, but it is not the only one.

The most general solution in this situation is to use [`Dispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) object associated with the element you're trying to access.

If you're targeting .NET 4.5 or newer, you can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199389(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Invoke` method:

```
var isChecked = targetCheckBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => targetCheckBox.IsChecked));
```

In older versions of the framework you will have to fall back to [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var isChecked = (bool?)targetCheckBox.Dispatcher
    .Invoke(new Func<bool?>(() => targetCheckBox.IsChecked));
```

Answer (score 1):

Databind the checkbox to a property in your view model, which is probably where this logic belongs to begin with.